# Using URL rewrite to add parameters to a url

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, url-rewriting

I try to use URL rewrite IIS module in order to modify a url into another url having a parameter contained in the path of the original url .

Exp :
Original URL : myurl/specialattribute_123456

Wanted URL : myurl?specialattribute=123456

I've use the URL rewrite module and generated in the web.config this tag :

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
    <rule name="RedirectRule1" stopProcessing="true">
         <match url=".*/specialattribute_(.*)/" />
         <action type="Redirect" url="myurl?specialattribute={R:1}" />
                </rule>
     </rules>
     <outboundRules>
          <preConditions>
               <preCondition name="ResponseIsHtml1">
                     <add input="{RESPONSE_CONTENT_TYPE}" pattern="^text/html" />
               </preCondition>
           </preConditions>
     </outboundRules>
</rewrite>
```

But it didn't work ... any help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved :

what's in url in the match tag is what comes after the base url of your website.

`<match url="specialattribute_(.*)" />
                    <action type="Redirect" url="myurl?webserviceid={R:1}" redirectType="Temporary" />`

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
<match url="*/specialattribute_*" />
         <action type="Redirect" url="myurl?specialattribute={R:2}" />
```

Just make sure that you are using "Wildcards" in your UrlRewrite module rule settings.

Comment: Thanks for answering me , there was the error where '*' and '/' can't be successive ... Still stuck

Answer (score 0):

Your issue belongs in the pattern you are using.

Your rule doesn't match `myurl/specialattribute_123456` but does match `myurl/specialattribute_123456/`.

If you want your pattern to match `myurl/specialattribute_123456` as in your example, change your rule pattern to (simply remove the trailing `/`):

```
<match url=".*/specialattribute_(.*)" />
```

Comment: Thanks, I did what you suggested but ... I have a 404 not found for myurl/specialattribute_123 ... May it be a problem with the inbound/outbound thing ? I've read [link](http://forums.iis.net/t/1173449.aspx/1) that Inbound rules are used to modify HTTP request URLs while outbound rules are used to modify HTTP responses. Maybe that's the problem ...

Comment: What do you want to use the `outboundRules` for? What if you take it off?

Comment: I've put this :
<rewrite>
    <rules>
    <rule name="RedirectRule1" stopProcessing="true">
 <match url=".*/specialattribute_(.*)" />
         <action type="Redirect" url="myurl?param1={R:2}" />
     </rule>
     </rules>
  <!--
     <outboundRules>
          <preConditions>
               <preCondition name="ResponseIsHtml1">
                     <add input="{RESPONSE_CONTENT_TYPE}" pattern="^text/html" />
               </preCondition>
           </preConditions>
     </outboundRules>
  -->
</rewrite>

Same error when browsing for myurl/specialattribute_123

of course myurl only works fine

Comment: That's because your are using an invalid back reference `{R:2}`. Change it to `{R:1}` and it should work.

Comment: Still the same error ... I think the problem is that the url I put is not recognized even though I test it , because when I put a (.*) as a pattern , the url is recognized

Comment: What url are you using? The same as in your question `myurl/specialattribute_123456`?

Comment: This pattern `.*/specialattribute_(.*)` will match `myurl/specialattribute_123456`. I have the exact same rewrite configuration on a test server than you have (except for the pattern that I changed to the one in my answer) and I get redirected every time...can you try to use the [failed-request tracing module](http://www.iis.net/learn/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis)?